# Convert Equation String to Int

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to convert a string like so:

```
var equation = "8+3*4/5-1*(5+5)"
```

to an Int so that it will calculate it with order of operations but with my code it is just return nil. Here is what I have tried

```
var answer = Int(equation)
```

Comment: Hi there Chad. Don't worry if your questions get edited here by others - it is quite normal here, and really you should only roll back if an edit changes the meaning of your post. There is a strong community preference for chat like "please help", "thanks in advance", "hi", "regards" etc to be trimmed out. Furthermore, we tend to discourage text-speak as well - Stack Overflow is a professional resource, and so we like to keep it reasonably readable! Thanks.

Comment: (I'm downvoting as I've just noticed you've reverted me twice - if it happens again I'll raise a moderator report).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
var equation = "\(8+3*4/5-1*(5+5))"  //"0"
```

And this way you can convert it to `Int`

```
var answer = equation.toInt()  // 0
```

Or you can directly do it this way:

```
var equation = 8+3*4/5-1*(5+5)   // 0
```

And As Martin R suggested if you want to do math operation in a string you can do it this way:

```
let expn = NSExpression(format:"8+3*4/5-1*(5+5)")
println(expn.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil))  //"0"
```

Which will result as `String` but you can convert it to `Int` as I suggested above.

Here is original link for math operation in a string: [Swift - Resolving a math operation in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719180/swift-resolving-a-math-operation-in-a-string)

Comment: Nope, same result answer is still nil

Comment: NSExpression is a fantastic class :)